# MySqli looping with stored results

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I looked at the prepared statements in MySqli and everything worked fine from a filtering point of view (personID has to be numeric). But, when I use the store_result (to loop on the records) then filtering seems to stop. For example:

```
$personID = 4;
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT personName FROM people WHERE personID>?")) {
$stmt->bind_param("s",$personID);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($personName);

//$stmt->fetch();
//$stmt->fetch_row();
  while($stmt->fetch()){
      echo $personName."<br /><br />";
  }
  $stmt->close();
}
```

That works fine but if I set:

```
$personID = 'bbccc';
```

It brings back all records, that is, it stops the type check and brings back all records. So How do I maintain the filtering?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely because MySQL is casting the string `bbccc` to an integer, the result of which is 0.  You are then in effect selecting all records where `personId > 0`, which is probably all or all but one of your rows.

If `$personID` is to be an integer value, you should bind it as such, rather than as a string:

```
$stmt->bind_param("i", $personID);
```

To see this behavior in action, execute the following query:

```
mysql> SELECT CAST('bbbcc' AS UNSIGNED);
+---------------------------+
| CAST('bbbcc' AS UNSIGNED) |
+---------------------------+
|                         0 | 
+---------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, makes sense but do I have to type check all params? I tried the $stmt->bind_param("i", $personID); but php\mysqli still tries to parse an int with the same results. Thanks again.

Comment: @user1002120 The bound parameter will only ensure that what goes to the database is the type it expects. It won't abort if the type is incorrect - that's still the responsibility of your application.